# Transferring Windows XP Mode VM to Another Machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I've been running Windows XP mode on my Windows 7 Laptop for a while now and I've got my VM set up just how I like it.

I am switchign laptops due to an intermittent hardware failure. Is it possible to transfer my Windows XP mode VM to my new laptop?

I know it's just a Windows Virtual PC VM, how would I go about transferring it if this is possible?

Will the Fact that I'm moving from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Pro make a difference? AFAIK they both support Windows XP Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [article by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TransferringMovingAVHDFromWindowsVirtualPCWindowsXPModeToAnotherComputer.aspx) on how to do this. I've yet to try it out though...